# Scrapy cannot extract text

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

i m using learning scrapy but i m stuck at something
website i use is https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/category-image/

i am extracting certain text on webpage
i use fallowing commands

```
fetch("https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/category-image/")
response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]').extract_first()
```

Output :

```
'<span class="plugin-author">\n\t\t\t<i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-users"></i> Muhammad Said El Zahlan\t\t</span>'
```

i need to extract Muhammad Said El Zahlan

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]/text()').extract_first()
```

Output:

```
'\n\t\t\t'

response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]/@span/text()').extract_first()

response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]/@span').extract_first()

response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]/@text()').extract_first()
```

Get me some clue

Answer (score 0):

use

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]/text()')[1].extract()
```

Output:

```
' Muhammad Said El Zahlan\t\t'
```

Comment: `response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]/text()')[0].extract()`

Comment: but output is `'\n\t\t\t'`

Comment: and then with [2] `response.xpath('//*[@class="plugin-author"]/text()')[2].extract()`

Comment: but output is same as [0] `'\n\t\t\t'`

Comment: How to remove \t\t from **Output**

Answer (score 0):

Here's youre xml tree:

```
<span class="plugin-author">
    <i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-users">
    </i> Muhammad Said El Zahlan\t\t
</span>
```

In other words you want `span/i/text()`:

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="plugin-author"]/i/text()').extract()
```

or `span//text`: (any text under span)

```
response.xpath('//span[@class="plugin-author"]//text()').extract()
```